# how to get intent data from arraylist after marker click on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, arraylist, marker

I'm using array list to show different organization locations (marker) using for loop.

```
private void addMarkers() {
if (googleMap != null) {

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> organizationList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)in.getSerializableExtra("organization");

    for(int i = 0; i < organizationList.size(); i++) {
        name = organizationList.get(i).get(TAG_NAME);
        latitude = organizationList.get(i).get(TAG_LATITUDE);
        longitude = organizationList.get(i).get(TAG_LONGITUDE);

        lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        longi = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,longi)).title(name).visible(true));

    }
```

this is the following code which make action on clicking marker

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
Log.i("GoogleMapActivity", "onMarkerClick");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);

in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
in.putExtra(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
in.putExtra(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
startActivity(in);
return false;}
```

i know putExtra is giving value of last value of for loop..... please help me to send exact value of marker clicked for another class

Comment: What you want actually? i dont understand. edit your question with more information

Comment: Inside onMarkerClick, loop your organizationList again an check if marker Title = organization name, then you have the right organisation and you can put it in the intent.

Comment: thank you Francesco verheye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i solved

```
  @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
Log.i("GoogleMapActivity", "onMarkerClick");

Intent intent = getIntent();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> organizationList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)intent.getSerializableExtra("organization");

for(int i = 0; i < organizationList.size(); i++) {
    name = organizationList.get(i).get(TAG_NAME);

    if(marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){

        latitude = organizationList.get(i).get(TAG_LATITUDE);
        longitude = organizationList.get(i).get(TAG_LONGITUDE);

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
        in.putExtra(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
        in.putExtra(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        startActivity(in);

    }

}

return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),arg0.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);

        in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
        in.putExtra(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
        in.putExtra(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        startActivity(in);

    }
```